# Making environment variables work after deployment in heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, environment-variables, dotenv

I have made a small nodejs project. I have some apis which are called from the server and I am using environment variables to protect the apikeys from public exposure. I have the keys declared in an .env file and In my server.js file I have them set up like this.

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const geonamesKey = process.env.GEONAMES_KEY

Now they work perfectly fine in my local machine but when I deployed my project to Heroku they are not working anymore. How do I fix this thing so that heroku can use the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found the solution. For this purpose I have to make use of the Config Vars in the app settings in heorku and put my keys and their value there. That solved my problem and my app is now working fine.